# Bootstrap 3's Split button caret height is smaller than the main button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap 3's button with attached drop-up menu](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup) using this code:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Remittance Summary</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Close Advice</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the caret is rendered smaller that the left button.

[Remittance Summary.png http://derp.co.uk/3576a](http://derp.co.uk/3576a)

However, including text *with* the caret apparently removes the problem:

[Remittance Summary.fixed.png http://derp.co.uk/5d282](http://derp.co.uk/5d282)

I'm wondering why does the caret not the same height with the left button? There is no `.css` loaded that overrides bootstrap's. And this button group is found at a modal-footer, if that helps.

---

I found the problem: The brower applies `auto` to the `height` of the caret button instead of applying the default `34px`. I wonder why?

Comment: Seems good **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x3yjv6m4/)**

Comment: can not reproduce your problem, please tell us what browser are you using

Comment: @Phoenix It's on Google Chrome 44.0.2403.89 m (64-bit). See my edit...

Comment: @Gideon I can't get ur problem on the same browser

Comment: Note there are some bugs to do with glyphicons in a button group and Chrome https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15497

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checking it's css property, its `height` is set to `auto`. It's grey-out thought so I cannot trace where it was set.

[chrome-css.png http://derp.co.uk/6d6ba](http://derp.co.uk/6d6ba)

So I forced a property to it via:

```
button.btn.dropdown-toggle {
    height: 34px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is a common problem and I thought to share my idea as I also faced this problem and the simple solution was to change doctype defition of your html page.No need to add any other css propoerties.Just check you doctype definition.
It should be

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> ```

.Bootstrap works fine from HTML5 and above....

Refer [Bootstrap Documenation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: Incredible! Thanks so much for this - I've just spent a considerable amount of time pulling the code of this button down down to bear bones to fix this problem. Who'd have thought it was a doctype error!

Answer (score 1):

This is still a problem if you use a input checkbox in the button but I also located a fix:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><input type="checkbox"/></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Remittance Summary</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Close Advice</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6opp372f/)

[Fixed Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p59Fq/)